# Send a content of datatable via mail

Tags: jsf-2

I'm new in jsf and i'm developping an project with jsf and hibenate it's my data access layer , I have a dataTable with primefaces
So i search how to send a content of this datatable via mail

Can you please help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always just drop the data into an email. Just look at the code for the managed bean that is your dataTable value, that will show you have to get your data. Combine that will some JavaMail code and you can send the data out in any format you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [PrimeFaces DataTable Exporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporter.jsf) to export results as PDF (additionally XML, XLS, CSV) file. Then use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to send mail with that file as an attachment.

Comment: thanks , i work with primefaces 3.0 and i have problems with export as pdf or (XML, XLS, CSV) ,my jar in the project is  primefaces 3.0 , so i can find another way without changer the jar to snapshot ??

Comment: Well I think you need to find out the solution to the problem to make exporter work. That would be the most correct way. Anyways you can take a backdoor and a longer way, get an example of Exporter from PrimeFaces sources. You can also implement exporter yourself, in PDF case - using iText or Apache PDFBox.